# Не работает pip только в python 3.11

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-10, pip, python-3.11

У меня стояли python 3.8 и 3.10. 
Я увидел, что вышел python 3.11, и решил его установить. Но в нём у меня не работает pip.
При этом с python 3.10 и 3.8 pip отлично работает.

```
D:\Programs>Python310\python.exe -m pip install pip -U -i https://pypi.org/simple
Requirement already satisfied: pip in d:\programs\python310\lib\site-packages (22.3.1)

D:\Programs>Python311\python.exe -m pip install pip -U -i https://pypi.org/simple
Requirement already satisfied: pip in d:\programs\python311\lib\site-packages (22.3.1)
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение', None, 10054, None))': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение', None, 10054, None))': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение', None, 10054, None))': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение', None, 10054, None))': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение', None, 10054, None))': /simple/pip/

D:\Programs>Python38\python.exe -m pip install pip -U -i https://pypi.org/simple
Requirement already satisfied: pip in d:\programs\python38\lib\site-packages (22.1)
Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-22.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (2.1 MB)
Installing collected packages: pip
  Attempting uninstall: pip
    Found existing installation: pip 22.1
    Uninstalling pip-22.1:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-22.1
Successfully installed pip-22.3.1

D:\Programs>
```

**UPDATE:**
Лог при запуске с параметром --log

```
2022-11-23T22:56:00,470 Using pip 22.3.1 from D:\Programs\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.11)
2022-11-23T22:56:00,472 Non-user install because site-packages writeable
2022-11-23T22:56:00,556 Created temporary directory: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-tracker-bg9g19ch
2022-11-23T22:56:00,557 Initialized build tracking at C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-tracker-bg9g19ch
2022-11-23T22:56:00,558 Created build tracker: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-tracker-bg9g19ch
2022-11-23T22:56:00,558 Entered build tracker: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-tracker-bg9g19ch
2022-11-23T22:56:00,561 Created temporary directory: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pjdbf4nv
2022-11-23T22:56:00,565 Created temporary directory: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-ephem-wheel-cache-aafssd1u
2022-11-23T22:56:00,597 Requirement already satisfied: pip in d:\programs\python311\lib\site-packages (22.3.1)
2022-11-23T22:56:00,601 1 location(s) to search for versions of pip:
2022-11-23T22:56:00,601 * https://pypi.org/simple/pip/
2022-11-23T22:56:00,602 Fetching project page and analyzing links: https://pypi.org/simple/pip/
2022-11-23T22:56:00,603 Getting page https://pypi.org/simple/pip/
2022-11-23T22:56:00,604 Found index url https://pypi.org/simple
2022-11-23T22:56:00,814 WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение', None, 10054, None))': /simple/pip/
2022-11-23T22:56:01,492 WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение', None, 10054, None))': /simple/pip/
2022-11-23T22:56:02,703 WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение', None, 10054, None))': /simple/pip/
2022-11-23T22:56:04,809 WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение', None, 10054, None))': /simple/pip/
2022-11-23T22:56:09,003 WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение', None, 10054, None))': /simple/pip/
2022-11-23T22:56:10,191 Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: connection error: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение', None, 10054, None))) - skipping
2022-11-23T22:56:10,197 Skipping link: not a file: https://pypi.org/simple/pip/
2022-11-23T22:56:10,198 Given no hashes to check 0 links for project 'pip': discarding no candidates
2022-11-23T22:56:10,213 Created temporary directory: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-unpack-xtov80ee
2022-11-23T22:56:10,531 Remote version of pip: 22.3.1
2022-11-23T22:56:10,532 Local version of pip:  22.3.1
2022-11-23T22:56:10,538 Was pip installed by pip? True
2022-11-23T22:56:10,539 Removed build tracker: 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-tracker-bg9g19ch'
```

Comment: Переустановить python и перезагрузить компьютер не помогает.

Comment: Почитайте тут комментарии https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/7424 может быть связано с не работающей проксей в винде. Кстати, укажите ОС в тегах к вопросу.

Comment: @CrazyElf Я удалил запись, но это не помогло.

Comment: Ну, с новыми версиями всегда какие-то проблемы. Поэтому на них сразу и не переходят обычно )  Проще подождать, пока все баги починят.